# Callback when angular is fully loaded

Tags: jquery, angular

I have to know when my script is fully loaded. I have tried some jQuery "on website load" but this doesn't work, angular is loading asynchronously, and this is the problem for me. Any idea how to know when angular is ready?

The page is uploaded to:
https://test2.iform.com.pl/imos-p.html

Code:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html style="height:100%;">
    <head>
        <title>TODO supply a title</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <style type="text/css">
            #ng-app, #ng-app > div, .main-content {height:100%;}
        </style>
        <script type="text/javascript">             
        var imosNetData = Object.assign({
            apiKey: '4ewrt6789io',
            session: 'session123',
              mode: 'catalog',
              catalog: '2168_1',
              showBasketButton: false,
             showPriceButton: false,
            onBasketButtonEnabled: function(isEnabled) {
                console && console.log('onBasketButtonEnabled(): ', isEnabled);
            },
            onBeforeAddArticle: function(article, pVarString) {
                console && console.log('onBeforeAddArticle(): article: ', article);
                console && console.log('onBeforeAddArticle(): pVarString: ', pVarString);
                return true;
            },
            onAddArticle: function(status, data) {
                console && console.log('onAddArticle(): status: ', status);
                console && console.log('onAddArticle(): data: ', data);
            },
            onBeforeCalculatePrice: function() {
                console && console.log('onBeforeCalculatePrice()');
            },
            onCalculatePrice: function(price) {
                console && console.log('onCalculatePrice(): ', price);
            }     

        });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body style="height: 100%; padding: 60 60 60 60; overflow:scroll;">
        <div style="height: 100%;">
            <script src="https://2168.netshop.imos3d.com/app/loader.js"></script>
        </div>
    </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: don''t mix angular with  jQuery

Comment: to be more clear: you have 3 scripts on the page, "your own script", "jQuery" and "Angular". The sequence you want is: (1) your script (2) Jquery (3) Angular -- kindly confirm the sequence and you want to make changes to which of the 3 scripts ??

Comment: So angular page is loaded from different server and I don't have access to this service. The sequence is: 1, 3, 2.
(1) - i have to generate unique session
(3) - we load angular page
(2) - I would like to add some changes in angular view